# Problems with importing and using json file in nuxt.config.js

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm having a problem with Nuxt 2 (v2.15) and server side rendering mode. I want to create an universal project that can be used as basis for other projects. Therefore, I have separated all of the logic and settings in 2 parts - core part and site-specific. I want to split settings that should be used in nuxt.config.js also so there are core settings that are used always and site specific settings that should be coded specifically for the site.

Idea is to create spearate files that will hold specific parts of core settings that would be imported into the nuxt.config.js and then merged with site specific parts that should be writen directly in nuxt.config.js.

The problem I have is that when I use import statement to import core settings (in the beginning of the nuxt.config.js) that will be then added in the Nuxt settings object everything works fine when I'm making the first request and everything renders on the server. When I want to navigate to some other page after hydration, application depends on server middleware that handles headless API and it simply doesn't work anymore. Call that should be handled by server middleware hangs. The moment I return those settings directly written into the Nuxt config object and not imported, everything works fine.

lets say, if I have something like this:

nuxt.config.js:

```
export default {
  ...
  serverMiddleware: [
    {
      'path': '/headless',
      'handler': '~/core/server-middleware/headless.js'
    },
  ]
  ...
```

everything works fine.

If I have server-middleware.js file that I import into nuxt.config.js it works only on server side and not on client side.

server-middleware.js:

```
export default [
  {
      'path': '/headless',
      'handler': '~/core/server-middleware/headless.js'
    },
];
```

nuxt.config.js:

```
import serverMiddleware from 'path/to/server-middleware.js';

export default {
  ...
  serverMiddleware: serverMiddleware
  ...
```

This works only on the server side. When page renders and get hydrated on the client side, every request to the address that begins with /headless simply hangs until promise fails. It never enters the server middleware code.

The only difference is that in second example I import JSON with middlewares config instead of simply putting that JSON directly in nuxt.config.js.

Thanks in advance,
Goran

Comment: How do you reach `/headless`? The initial render is done on the server, after the hydration, your app is basically an SPA. Do you use axios/fetch to get on the path `/headless` or do you access it in some other way (because it should indeed not work)?

Comment: I believe that is irrelevant. /headless is handles by server middleware code that uses axios in order to fetch data. It works fine before and after hydration if there is no import of JSON that describes server middlewares and configuration is coded directly in nuxt.config.js. If I import that JSON, as shown above, it doesn't work after hydration.

Comment: How do you import it exactly?

Comment: Like stated above:

`import serverMiddleware from 'path/to/server-middleware.js';`